# Saga from redux-saga is being ignored, only the reducer is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

Having a problem with `redux-saga` here. I am calling `toggleSidebar()` to open / close the sidebar. That works, however, the saga is ignored. I log to the console using `console.log` in my `reducer` and `saga`, but only the `reducer` logs to the console.

The sidebar opens / closes, but why is the saga being ignored?

> /sagas/templateSaga.js - Does not log to the console

```
import { FETCH_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE, RECEIVE_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE } from '../actions'

function* toggleSidebar(action) {
  console.log("Called toggleSidebar in Saga")
  yield put({type: 'TOGGLE_SIDEBAR', data: action.payload});
}


export default function* templateSaga() {
  yield takeLatest("TOGGLE_SIDEBAR", toggleSidebar);
}
```

> /reducers/templateReducer.js - Logs to the console

```
export default (state = initialState, {type, data = ""}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case TOGGLE_SIDEBAR: {
      console.log("Called toggleSidebar in reducer");
      return {...state, collapsed: data}
    }
    default: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> /actions/index.js

```
export const TOGGLE_SIDEBAR = 'TOGGLE_SIDEBAR'
export const toggleSidebar = data => ({type: TOGGLE_SIDEBAR, data})
```

> /reducers/index.js ( rootReducer )

```
import templateReducer  from './templateReducer'

export default combineReducers({
  templateReducer
})
```

> /sagas/index.js ( rootSaga )

```
import templateSaga from './templateSaga'

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    ...templateSaga
  ])
}
```

My store is configured like that:

```
import createSagaMiddleware                      from 'redux-saga'
import rootReducer     from '../modules/reducers'
import rootSaga from '../modules/sagas'

const sagaMiddleware    = createSagaMiddleware(rootSaga);

const middleware = [
  sagaMiddleware,
  routerMiddleware(history)
]

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

And finally, in my App I am using:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  template: state.templateReducer
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators({ toggleSidebar }, dispatch)


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably in `/sagas/index.js` ( rootSaga )
Try to change `...templateSaga` to `fork(templateSaga)` like so:

```
import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { templateSaga } from './templateSaga'

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(templateSaga)
  ])
}
```

And change `export default function* templateSaga` to

```
export function* templateSaga() {
  yield takeLatest("TOGGLE_SIDEBAR", toggleSidebar);
}
```

Also, you have some kind of a loop in `/sagas/templateSaga.js` where you take `'TOGGLE_SIDEBAR'` and dispatch the same type right away

Comment: Right in every aspect. Just noticed the loop, awkward. Thought that's the flow for redux-saga. I just want to dispatch the action and change the state.

Do I have to create another actiontype for that, or is there another approach? Since I import templateSaga() in my rootSaga which is then listening for actions. Should I dispatch it right awat in the templateSaga() function?

Comment: here is a really good article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/async-operations-using-redux-saga-2ba02ae077b3

Comment: if you'd like to change state you should do it in reducers. It all depends on how you want to structure the app, but basically calling `toggleSidebar` action in your component is enough to trigger reducer. Saga is needed for complex async communications